# How to stop streaming tweets after a time interval?

Tags: python, streaming, tweepy

Using the `tweepy` python library, how can I stop streaming tweets after x seconds?

The `StreamListener` from `tweepy.streaming` continuously collects data until the user manually shuts down the program. However, I only want to collect tweets for a user defined time interval.

Comment: Many people had the same issue and there was no proper solution. So I decided to post my own hack to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve this problem - multi-threading and creating a user defined `StreamListener`. I will highlight one way to solve this and explain why I feel it is the best.

There is no need to create any user defined instances of classes unless you want to override the built-in functionality (for storing tweets)

```
import tweepy
import time
from tweepy import Stream, StreamListener, OAuthHandler


'''Authenticate user'''
CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxxxxx'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxxxxx'
auth = OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)


'''How long do you want to stream tweets (in seconds)'''
runtime = 60 #this means one minute


'''Start streaming'''
twitterstream = Stream(auth, StreamListener())

twitterstream.filter(track=['twitter'], async=True) #apply any filter you want

time.sleep(runtime) #halts the control for runtime seconds

twitterstream.disconnect() #disconnect the stream and stop streaming
```

This is a simple and elegant solution and works for all streams. There is no (complex) multi-threading involved.

Another common method I found across stackoverflow and many other websites refer to starting a timer inside a user defined `StreamListener` and checking whether the time limit has exceeded in the `self.on_data()` method. While this is a neat hack for high volume streams, it checks for the time limit exceeding only when the stream receives a tweet. This can be quite a huge problem if you are streaming low volume streams (when not many people are tweeting with the filter you applied).

Comment: would you please tell me If I do not stop stream calling disconnect will it cause any problem like app suspension.

Comment: @JahangirAlam I am not sure, especially with the updated Twitter API. I doubt your app will be "suspended." It is more likely that you will be rate limited and will be unable to connect to Twitter API until after a cooldown.

Comment: thank you for replying back. for clarification, when I run stream.filter() there will be a single persistent connection created right? if it creates single connection then why app gets suspended and rate limited. another query is I see my monthly tweet cap is not changing when I run the stream and consume tweets. thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: my bad luck, I used the twitterstream.disconnect() as you mentioned. but my app got suspended yesterday. I am finding no solution to this problem. becoming hopeless :(

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But I used their API in 2016 and not sure what's happening in your particular case. You may have better luck opening an issue on the repository - https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy